# Nextjs - link to '/' without refreshing

Tags: next.js

```
// import Link from "next/link";

<Link href="/">Home</Link>
```

A link to `/` refreshes the page. Is there anything I can do to stop the page from refreshing, whenever the user navigates to the homepage?

Answer (score 1):

Use this hook and you'll never have to use `Link` ever again. Just use regular HTML anchors and they'll work as you would expect.

```js
// useNextClickHandler.ts

import type { Router } from 'next/router'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

/**
 * Place this in a Next.js's _app.tsx component to use regular anchor elements
 * instead of Next.js's <code>Link</code> component.
 *
 * @param router - the Next.js router
 */
export default function useNextClickHandler(router: Router): void {
    useEffect(() => {
        async function onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
            // Only handle primary button click
            if (event.button !== 0) {
                return
            }

            // Use default handling of modifier+click events
            if (
                event.metaKey ||
                event.ctrlKey ||
                event.altKey ||
                event.shiftKey
            ) {
                return
            }

            const anchor = containingAnchor(event.target)

            // Only handle anchor clicks
            if (!anchor) {
                return
            }

            // Use default handling of target="_blank" anchors
            if (anchor.target === '_blank') {
                return
            }

            // If the link is internal, prevent default handling
            // and push the address (minus origin) to the router.
            if (anchor.href.startsWith(location.origin)) {
                event.preventDefault()
                await router.push(anchor.href.substr(location.origin.length))
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('click', onClick)

        return () => window.removeEventListener('click', onClick)
    }, [router])
}

function containingAnchor(
    target: EventTarget | null
): HTMLAnchorElement | undefined {
    let parent = target

    while (
        parent instanceof HTMLElement &&
        !(parent instanceof HTMLAnchorElement)
    ) {
        parent = parent.parentElement
    }

    return parent instanceof HTMLAnchorElement ? parent : undefined
}
```

```js
// _app.tsx

export default function App({
    Component,
    pageProps,
    router,
}: AppProps): JSX.Element {
    useNextClickHandler(router)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/navigate-between-pages/link-component) states this: When linking between pages on websites, you use the  HTML tag. In Next js you use the Link Component from next/link to wrap the  tag. it allows you to do client-side navigation to a different page in the application.

Just do

```
<Link href="/">
  <a>
    Home
  </a>
</Link>
```

Answer (score -1):

Other alternative is by using `next/router` and utilise `onClick` event.

```
import Router from "next/router";

<a onClick={() => Router.push("/")}">
  Home
</a>
```